# Getting 'shell returned -1073741571' when finding sum up to n terms using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I tried to find sum recursively but getting 'shell returned -1073741571' when I put large values for n. It is working for small values of n say 100. I feel this error is related to stack but not sure about its reason. I've increased recursion limit so that recursion limit is not hit. Here is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
def get_sum(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num + get_sum(num-1)

print(get_sum(10000))
```

Edit:
Specs: Windows 10, Python 3.7, Editor: Vim

I've also tried on PyCharm with Python version 3.6. Still same issue.

Comment: Can you list your system specs? I am getting the correct answer on a Ubuntu 18.04 with 4G RAM and Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setrecursionlimit only sets the limits within the python interpreter, on linux/unixish os'es check ulimit output for stack size limit.

Comment: Edited question. I'm actually on Windows 10.

Comment: same principal applies the OS has a set memory size value for a stack, python's setrecursionlimit is basically a safety mechanism to prevent you from blowing up the whole python interpreter.  

It will throw a catchable exception if you breach it.  Blowing up the entire stack does not result in a catchable exception it ends the OS process.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on my editor, I get this error:

> File "J:/maskros/Pithon/test.py", line 8, in get_sum
>
> return num + get_sum(num-1)
>
> [Previous line repeated 997 more times]
>
> MemoryError: Stack overflow

So it is because it hits the recursion limit, but when I set my recursion limit to a lower value, then it worked, If you reduce the setrecursion, to something like 10000, then it might work.

In comments it was noted that trying a lower value doesn't work.
The value mentioned did not work for me but this value did.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(4999)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())


def get_sum(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num + get_sum(num-1)

print(get_sum(4998))
```

So I would guess and check till I get a good value.

Comment: No, i tried setting low values for recursion, it didn't work.

Comment: What value did you try?